# Finding all $x$ above a value

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to find all indices of a vector, $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, that are above a given value, $a$. I write
\begin{align*}
I^* = \operatorname*{argmax}_{I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}}\sum_{n\in I}(x_n-a)
\end{align*}
Does this give me the right answer?

What's confusing to me is that $\operatorname{argmax}_xf(x) = \operatorname{argmax}_x(f(x)+c)$ for any $c$, so $I^*$ does not depend on $a$??

Comment: Your "$a$" does not play the same role of "$c$" in your second example, since the number of times that "$-a$" is summed depends on the set $I$ that is chosen. Your problem _almost_ gives the right answer for the desired set $I^*$, but it can have multiple answers in the case when some $x_i$ values are exactly equal to $a$. So the argmax is not unique and may not give the set $I^*$ you want.   Also, your argmax definition seems to be an indirect way to define $I^*$, I would prefer to simply define $I^*$ in words as you did in the first sentence.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your answer (post as answer and I will accept, I get +2 points, need all I can get! haha). So I guess I should write $I^*\in\arg\max_{I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}}\sum_{n\in I}(x_n-a)$ to solve your second point. I guess this is the same as writing $I^*\in\arg\max_{I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}}\sum_{n\in I}x_n-a|I|$?